# How to select elements in a Dataframe that is created from Global Temp View using Spark Sql

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, pyspark

I need to store an obect in Global Temp View and read values later using Spark Sql. I am getting an error while selecting from the dataframe which is created from the global temp view.

Error Message:
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 15 in stage 8.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 15.3 in stage 8.0 (TID 220) (10.139.64.4 executor 0): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException:

TypeError: StructType can not accept object 'conn_string' in type <class 'str'>

It is not due to any particular class attributes as it happens for several of them if I add more. The error is happening for the line "self.model_id = df.collect()[0][0]". I have commented few lines after that which also throws same error.

Any help is really appreciated.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

class Model:

    def __init__(self, model_id : int = None, model_name : str = None, conn_string : str = None) :
    self.model_id = model_id
    self.model_name = model_name
    self.conn_string = conn_string
    
    def save_to_temp(self):
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    
    schema: StructType = StructType([
    StructField('model_id', IntegerType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('model_name', StringType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('conn_string', StringType(), nullable=True)
    ])
    
    rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(self.__dict__)
    df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
    
    df.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("temp_tbl")
    
    def read_from_temp(self):
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    df = spark.sql("select * from global_temp.temp_tbl")
    
    self.model_id = df.collect()[0][0]
    
    df.show()
    dataCollect = df.collect()
    print(dataCollect)  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model_id = "1"
    model_name = "model name 1"
    conn_string = "conn_string 1"
    model1 = Model(model_id, model_name, conn_string)
    
    model1.save_to_temp()
    
    model2 = Model()
    print("Initialized model2")
    model2.read_from_temp()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert a spark temp table into a dataframe. The spark temp table was created with a struct and you can't do the reverse while reading from it.

May be you can convert the dictionary into a json and then store it as a data frame into the temp table

Comment: I think there should be a way to convert a spark temp table into a dataframe. While writing into the temp view, first I had to convert the dictionary into an RDD and then into a DF. If I don't convert into an RDD, I was getting a similar TypeError. Similarly, I think I may need to apply the schema while converting the temp view into dataframe. I am new to Python and I can't figure out a way to do it. Sorry for the indentation as stackoverflow wouldn't allow me to keep proper indentation.